Parallel block cipher in CTR mode and variable number of threads: how to deal with internal state and permit decryption?
I'm implementing a parallel block cipher (Morus, to be precise) in CTR mode and I'd like to make it flexible with respect to the number of threads. It is not difficult per se, as I can partition the message and distribute chunks to any number of threads quite easily, since CTR mode permits an embarrassingly parallel implementation with basically no challenges. Let's say a user decides to encrypt their code with 2 threads, and let's say that my implementation assigns to every thread the same (IV, key) pair. The second half of the first chunk will be encrypted by a cipher whose internal state depends on the previous steps, i.e., initialization with IV+key and encryption of the first half of the chunk.
Now, let's say that the same user attempts decrypting the same message with 4 threads. The second thread will tackle its chunk decryption (which is the second half of the first chunk from encryption step) right after initialization with IV+key. So, it will decrpyt that part of the message in a different state from the one in which it was encrypted. Will the decryption have success!? I think it won't, because that invisible internal state contributes to the output.
So, if that is the case, how can I achieve my purpose? Should I initialize the cipher at every block encryption/decryption (so once every 16/32 bytes, multiple times per thread)? Any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

It seems this is your programmatic problem. CTR mode has a random access property both for encryption and description. If a thread cannot decrypt properly, it is not the thread's problem, but rather your (understanding | programmatic) error.

I'm not saying it's CTR mode's fault, I'm just saying: do you think init'ing at every block is the only solution to avoid this? Yes, it's a "programmatic" problem. Is this the wrong place to ask these kinds of question? If so, I'm sorry, I'll move elsewhere.

I'm not sure you will get an answer in [so], coding-related questions are handled there even cryptographic. You need to use the same key for each thread and run the key schedule, then with the given IV and starting index, you can decrypt all correctly.
